# how do I get the text right in a multiple page microsoft word table?

Tags: ms-word, text-formatting

I have a microsoft word table that I need to extend across multiple pages. Each additional page after the first one needs to have the text "Table 3.1. Continued" at the top. This table is being embedded in a text document over 90 pages long. I can't have empty space (despite the fact that it makes the document more readable) and the table has to come right after it gets mentioned in the text.

How do I do this?

I've tried manually cutting the table into pieces, putting those pieces into a text box, and then putting the textbox in the document. The problem with that is I then have random singular lines of text that are outside of the margin and won't go to the next page no matter what settings I select (including giving the textbox literal pages of space) (see bottom of pic). [screen snip of attempt to add table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM3Tq.png)

I've tried every formatting setting I can find and nothing seems to fix this, whether I mess with the image formatting or paragraph formatting. My last option is to manually create a series of blank pages using a page break. I'd really like to avoid that since changing just one line (which is likely to happen) would then require me to completely redo all of that.

Thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: You just want: 1. Tables not to span pages, and if they do, to repeat "Table 3.1. Continued" at the top of each page. 2. Try to leave no blank space between the tables and the context, right? Could you please attach a graphic of the results you want?